# Mailman3 fails to start Postorius

Tags: apache2, mailman

I have installed mailman3 on a Ubuntu 20.04 instance in the cloud.
First, it wouldn't start, now I have done a complete reinstall from scratch, now it is running. I can create a mailinglist, a rest runner is running.

I'm now wondering what I need to do to access the Postorius web ui. I copied the `apache.conf` file to my apache2 `sites-enabled` directory, but still nothing shows up at the url I think it uses. Docs say the url is `ipnr/postorius/lists`. Is that correct? What am I missing if I get a 404?

This is the apache2 conf file in sites-enabled:

```
Alias /mailman3/favicon.ico /var/lib/mailman3/web/static/postorius/img/favicon.ico
Alias /mailman3/static      /var/lib/mailman3/web/static
<Directory "/var/lib/mailman3/web/static">
        Require all granted
</Directory>
<IfModule mod_proxy_uwsgi.c>
        ProxyPass /mailman3/favicon.ico !
        ProxyPass /mailman3/static !
        ProxyPass /mailman3 unix:/run/mailman3-web/uwsgi.sock|uwsgi://localhost/
</IfModule>
```

This is output from `systemctl status mailman3`:

```
● mailman3.service - Mailman3 server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mailman3.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2021-03-27 20:21:02 UTC; 13h ago
       Docs: man:mailman(1)
             https://mailman.readthedocs.io/
   Main PID: 1457 (python3)
      Tasks: 15 (limit: 2345)
     Memory: 691.2M
     CGroup: /system.slice/mailman3.service
             ├─1457 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/lib/mailman3/bin/master --force -C /etc/mailman3/mailman.cfg
             ├─1815 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/lib/mailman3/bin/runner -C /etc/mailman3/mailman.cfg --runner=archive:0:1
             ├─1816 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/lib/mailman3/bin/runner -C /etc/mailman3/mailman.cfg --runner=bounces:0:1
             ├─1817 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/lib/mailman3/bin/runner -C /etc/mailman3/mailman.cfg --runner=command:0:1
             ├─1818 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/lib/mailman3/bin/runner -C /etc/mailman3/mailman.cfg --runner=in:0:1
             ├─1821 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/lib/mailman3/bin/runner -C /etc/mailman3/mailman.cfg --runner=lmtp:0:1
             ├─1822 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/lib/mailman3/bin/runner -C /etc/mailman3/mailman.cfg --runner=nntp:0:1
             ├─1823 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/lib/mailman3/bin/runner -C /etc/mailman3/mailman.cfg --runner=out:0:1
             ├─1824 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/lib/mailman3/bin/runner -C /etc/mailman3/mailman.cfg --runner=pipeline:0:1
             ├─1825 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/lib/mailman3/bin/runner -C /etc/mailman3/mailman.cfg --runner=rest:0:1
             ├─1826 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/lib/mailman3/bin/runner -C /etc/mailman3/mailman.cfg --runner=retry:0:1
             ├─1827 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/lib/mailman3/bin/runner -C /etc/mailman3/mailman.cfg --runner=virgin:0:1
             └─1828 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/lib/mailman3/bin/runner -C /etc/mailman3/mailman.cfg --runner=digest:0:1
Mar 27 20:20:51 lists systemd[1]: Starting Mailman3 server...
Mar 27 20:20:58 lists mailman3[657]: Starting Mailman's master runner
Mar 27 20:20:59 lists systemd[1]: mailman3.service: Can't open PID file /run/mailman3/master.pid (yet?) after start: Operation not permitt>
Mar 27 20:21:02 lists systemd[1]: Started Mailman3 server.
```

Comment: Did you restart/reload Apache after adding the file? What does that file contain?

Comment: I edited my question. Yes, I did restart apache.

Comment: According to that config, the base path is `/mailman3`, not `/postorius`.

Comment: Wow. Silly me. I thought I know quite a lot about apache. Never too old to learn. Thank you so much. If you post your comment as an answer, I can accept it.